# Calculate GPS coordinates from a starting point

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, math, gps

Is there a library (JS or .NET) or a set of formulas that would help me calculate set of gps coordinates based on starting location, direction and distance.

For example.

I have an exact lon/lat of a certain location. I'd like to calculate an exact lon/lot 5 miles NE from that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript you can use the [geodesy](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy) library (under the MIT license), which is the code behind the [Movable-Type.co.uk](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website.

For example:

```
const LatLon = require('geodesy').LatLonSpherical;

const p1 = new LatLon(59.912140, 10.743796);
const distance = 42*10**3;
const bearing = 240.0

const p2 = p1.rhumbDestinationPoint(distance, bearing);

console.log(p2); // LatLon { lat: 59.72328246275707, lon: 10.093154371545552 }
```

This finds a second point given initial position, distance and bearing. This particular code is for Node, but it can also be used in the browser.

It should be noted that there are often several different ways to do the various calculations. Some are complex and accurate, while some are simple and less accurate. Using a spherical earth model, as I did in my example, is less accurate, but good enough for ordinary use.

Another library you could check out is [geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might or might not fit your needs but have you tried [Entity Framework Spatial?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh859721(v=vs.113).aspx)